# C# Encryption exception

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

i Team,

I have the following encryption code in C#. I am getting an exception as `Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.`

Could you please tell me what is the missing link here?

```
//Key and IV for RSA Encryption
byte[] ketByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A01S2");
byte[] IVByte =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3FG563570FG565C3CBB50FD805A01S2");

//Read image
Image sourceImg = Image.FromFile(@"D:\ImageSource\Cha1.bmp");

//Convert to Byte[]
byte[] byteArray = ImageToByteArray(sourceImg);

//Encrypt
byte[] encryptedByteArray = EncryptByte(byteArray, ketByte, IVByte);



public static byte[] EncryptByte(byte[] palinData, byte[] Key, byte[] theInitializationVector)
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael algorithm = System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael.Create();

            algorithm.Key = Key;
            algorithm.IV = theInitializationVector;  //Exception

            System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream cStream = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(ms,algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cStream.Write(palinData, 0, palinData.Length);
            cStream.Close();

            byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
            return encryptedData;
        }
```

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944833/specified-initialization-vector-iv-does-not-match-the-block-size-for-this-algor)

Answer (score 2):

From [SymmetricAlgorithm.IV Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv.aspx) documentation:

> The size of the IV property must be the same as the [BlockSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.blocksize.aspx) property.

And the BlockSize property:

> Gets or sets the block size, in bits, of the cryptographic operation.

i don't know how many bits the UTF-8 encoded form of "C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A01S2" is, but it's almost certainly not correct (Do you know how many bytes a UTF-8 encoded characters takes? i don't). You also don't know the blocksize of the Rijendal cipher, nor should you have to.

You should almost certainly be using [PasswordDeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes.aspx) instead:

```
PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = 
      new PasswordDeriveBytes("C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A01S2", null);

IVByte = pdb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8); //divide by 8 for bits to bytes
```

Finally, from a security point of view: while the **Key** is secret, the **Initialization Vector** (IV) is not. The IV is usually public, sent along with the encrypted data.  In other words, your **IV** should not be the same as the **Key**.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization vector isn't the correct size, IVs are usually 16 bytes.

Try halving the size of your vector:

```
byte[] IVByte =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3FG563570FG565C");
```

Comment: You're probably right, but he really should be asking the ciper object for its block size, and using that (in code)

Comment: And UTF-8 encoding really makes no sense here, not that I fault you for trying to give the OP an answer he can immediately understand.

Comment: I have only limited knowledge on encryption. Could you please tell why UTF-8 encoding does not make sense? And I have a general question. Suppose, I encode and encrypt like this, under any chance a second person can see the content of the file (if he is not having the key)?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect

```
byte[] ketByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A01S2");
byte[] IVByte =  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3FG563570FG565C3CBB50FD805A01S2");
```

are doing?  Because they are not loading those hex values into the byte array.  They are creating a 32-byte array containing the ASCII values of each character.